# 500 Internal Server Error en AJAX y php

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un problema en una web que cuando se abre manda llamar varias peticiones a la misma web.

El problema es que algunas peticiones las marca como **500 Internal Server Error**.

Cuando actualizo la página a veces completa todas las peticiones correctamente o bien se genera este error en las peticiones de manera aleatoria.

Anexo imagen:

[image: imagen de prueba]

No se si sea mi SERVIDOR WEB (en local en pc no había problemas). La solución rápida ahora que tengo es mandar llamar las 8 funciones pero de forma pausada.

En mi página tengo botones SIGUIENTE.. SIGUIENTE para que vaya avanzando en mis formularios a llenar por el usuario. En cada botón de SIGUIENTE le puse que mandara llamar de a 2 funciones y así es como ahorita lo tengo funcionando de este manera...

alguna sugerencia?

---

hoy sábado volvió a fallar y demasiado con lo mismo.... será el servidor?

Comment: Revisa el log de tu servidor, los errores 5xx son causados por algun problema en el servidor.

Comment: Si pusieses el código de facturar1_s.php/general_s.php sería mucho mas fácil que te ayuden. Por favor edita la pregunta para facilitarnos el poder ayudarte.

Comment: te recomendaria no utilizar mayúsculas en tus variables javascript. porque dierase la impresión de más que una variable ser una clase o método (función).

Comment: Hola gracias amigo. no se si sea mi SERVIDOR WEB (en local en pc no habia problemas)  las solución rapida ahoria que tengo es mandar llamar las 8 funciones pero de forma pausada.. en mi pagina tengo botones SIGUIENTE.. SIGUIENTE para que vaya avanznado en mis formularios a llenar por el usuairo... en cada boton de SIGUIENTE le puse que mandara llamar de a 2 funciones y asi es como ahorita lo tengo funcionando... alguna sugerente???

Comment: Hola Ing, ¿podrías revisar los logs de tu servidor web tal y como te indica @eyllanesc ? Por norma general los que provocan errores 500 se guardan en el log de error y no el de acceso. Con los mensajes de error podremos hacernos una idea de qué falla en tu aplicación.